# .Net Core how to get traceId Skywalking

Tags: skywalking

I'm using `SkyAPM.Agent.AspNetCore 1.1.0`, and I need to get the trace id in my code and do something.

However, I didn't find enough information anywhere. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the solution from the source code.
First inject the `IEntrySegmentContextAccessor` in the constuctor, then get the traceId by `_entrySegmentContextAccessor.Context.TraceId`